# Regex to delete multi line content between two specific words

Tags: python, regex

I have multiple instances of Fortran subroutines within a text file like the following:

```
SUBROUTINE ABCDEF(STRING1)
STRING2
STRING3
.
.
.
STRINGN
      END
```

How can I delete the subroutines with their content in python using regex?

I have already tried this piece of code without success:

```
with open(input, 'r') as file:
    output = open(stripped, 'w')
    try:
        for line in file:
            result = re.sub(r"(?s)SUBROUTINE [A-Z]{6}(.*?)\bEND\b", input)
            output.write("\n")
    finally:
        output.close()
```

Comment: Looks like just read entire file into a variable, then run the regex sub on it, then write out to a new file.

Comment: Do you mean you wish to delete each block of text that begins with a line that begins `"SUBROUTINE "` and ends with the first instance of a line that contains only `"END"`, possibly indented with spaces? If so, this looks like a job for the [flip-flop operator](https://pypi.org/project/flip-flop-operator/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work? I replaced input with input_file as input is a builtin function, so it's bad practice to use it.

```
pattern = r"(?s)SUBROUTINE [A-Z]{6}(.*?)\bEND\b"
regex = re.compile(pattern, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
with open(input_file, 'r') as file:
    with open(stripped, 'w') as output_file:
        result = regex.sub('', file.read())
        output_file.write(result)
```